# XML if statement?

Tags: xml, if-statement, syntax

Is it possible to have an if statement inside XML? I did some googling around and found this:

However I believe this is not working properly as I do not see the userId in my console, is my if statement syntax correct? (if user.id is not equal to nothing then do this) Code is below:

```
<if cond="#{user.id} != ''">
    <userId type="String">#{user.id}</userId>
</if>
```

Comment: XML is not an executable language.  So the only time you can have an if statement inside XML is if the particular XML parser supports it.   What XML parser are you using to open the XML with?